# OAuth2_GrantType_UserCredentials with Restler

Tags: restler

Does anybody have a sample with OAuth2_GrantType_UserCredentials and Restler ? 
I've tried myself but it's very difficult to understand

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your storage class, in my case PDO, you need to look at the following functions. Make sure you have your validations in the first one.

```
public function checkUserCredentials($email, $password) {}
public function getUserDetails($username) {}
```

Then

```
POST https://{your_server}/token
```

With the following payload (obviously changed to suit your environment):

```
email=me@myemail.com&
password=mypassword&
grant_type=password
client_id=myclient_id
```

The important one here is the grant_type, it actually is 'password' for what you are attempting.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're asking. If you have OAuth 2 set up already on your server, you just need to change the grant_type to 'client_credentials' and pass the client_id and client_secret in exchange for the token. For example, on my index.php page, I was able to get a token by passing:

index.php/grant?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=demoapp&client_secret=demopass

Hope this helps.